# grails bootrun hangs before starting up internal tomcat

Tags: grails, freeze, bootrun

The project has worked fine but suddenly it hangs on startup without any error.

Run-App --verbose --stacktrace give this print:

```
grails> run-app --verbose --stacktrace
| Running application...
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath> Configuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving depen> Configuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving depen:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:bootRun
2017-04-18 14:20:47.410 ERROR --- [           main] g.boot.config.tools.ClassPathScanner     : The application defines a Groovy source using the default package. Please move all Groovy sources into a package.
> Building 85% > :bootRun
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

> Building 85% > :bootRun
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI

> Building 85% > :bootRun
```

Can not see what's going on. I tried to clean up the build-directory but that didn't help.

The only things that's changed since working session is that I have added a few GSP-files. But can't think it would hang the startup, would it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this mysterious problem has got it's solution. 
I forgot to check if the database was ok in MSSQL. Well other databases that didn't used tcp worked but this one used port 49678 which now had been taken by the operating system.
Using the beautiful app "cports" I could see this:

```
services.exe    772 TCP 49678       ::          ::      Listening   services.exe    Operativsystemet Microsoft® Windows®    Tjänst- och styrenhetsapp   10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)  Microsoft Corporation   N/A             2017-04-18 14:58:44
```

So I changed the port used by MSSQL to 1433 and then the pain was over.